# A new convergence problem for the conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, conditional-convergence

You have risks $X_1$, $X_2$, ...

(they are assumed to be independent, but not necessarily identically distributed)

and

$S_n= X_1 + X_2 + \cdots +X_n$

QUESTION: under what reasonable conditions we have that

$\mathbb{E}[Xi | S_n]$ converges to $\mathbb{E}[Xi]$?

Comment: Is there anything specific you're looking for? Are the X_i's discrete, or continuous? Even though they aren't identically distributed, are their supports relatively similar or could they be wildly different?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You can assume that $X_i$ are continuous random variables and that their support is relatively similar.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the question is proving surprisingly tricky! I originally thought that by working with continuous random variables, we could at least avoid combinatorial considerations that pop up in the discrete case, but that's not the case. For example, let $G_i$ be a sequence of centered Gaussians with variance $2^{-i-10}$ and $B_i$ a sequence of Bernoulli(1/2) random variables. Then if $X_1 = G_1+B_1$ and $X_i = G_i+2B_i$ for $i > 1$, then $E[X_i|S_n]$ doesn't converge to $E[X_i]$ even though Var$(S_i) \to \infty$ and $X_i$ are $L^1$-bounded. So still working on it.